# What enables blood benders to levitate their victims?

Tags: science, the-legend-of-korra

In the episode **Out of the Past**, blood benders are seen being able to levitate their victims.

> Tarrlok levitates Korra all the way down the stairs into the strong room, and into her prison cell. Later in the same episode, Yakone clearly levitates Toph and brings her to open up his shackles. He also levitates Aang before delivering his final blow on him inside the courtroom.

I understand that a blood bender has power over his victim, but logically, shouldn't that power be restricted to the inherent abilities of the victim itself? What exactly would enable the blood bender to lift/levitate the victim?

Comment: I don't know why blood bending is so rare in Avatar. I get the whole taboo aspect, but blood is more than 50% water. Any amateur water bender should be able to blood blend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a subset of waterbending; a waterbender can cause water to levitate/fly/take a shape, so why should a bloodbender not be able to do this?  It seems like bloodbending does not affect the body (i.e. skeleton or muscle movement) of the victim, but the *location and configuration of his/her blood.*  Since blood is thoroughly contained within veins and arteries, moving it would also move the body, and if the bender maintains the configuration, the logical extension of this is levitation.

Comment: Truth be told, if it was really bending just blood, things would get very bloody very quickly (veins couldn't withstand that kind of pressure). But I guess this could work if it was bending all the water in the body, not just blood.

Comment: Good point.  I'm not up on biology enough to know what veins can and cannot do. Also, cartoon physics.

Comment: Actually, given the immense pressure with which blood is pumped through the body (A deep cut on the upper arm can squirt out several metres), arteries are surprisingly tough. If you were to disperse the pressure evenly enough, it's not unthinkable you could life the weight of a person wiithout bursting the arteries. 

What's less believable is how they don't undergo a billion strokes

Comment: Nice answer! It seems that I had misunderstood blood bending as some form of hypnotic control over the victim. Your point about blood benders controlling the location and configuration of the victim's _blood_ (and maybe _water_ too), rather than the _victim_ itself, makes sense.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It was stated by creators that "blood bending" is just the name of the technique, but it's not restricted to victim's blood but to all liquid of the body. Now I doubt that body's fat would count as a liquid avaliable to bend, but if it would then it's not that crazy that victims would levitate

Comment: Could you provide a quote?